# Is it possible to switch composite video on and off at will?

Tags: screen, composite-video

I want to use this small LCD screen with the Pi for a static application to display some information:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0056WJP1M/

I read in the reviews that it will switch on automatically when input is applied. Assuming it switches off when the signal is removed, this could be a way of controlling it remotely.

My question is. Is it possible to switch the RCA composite video out signal on and off via software, or is it always on?

Comment: Google `tvservice`.  `tvservice -o` turns video output off, `tvservice -p` turns it on with preferred settings. `tvservice -s` gives current status (on/off/configuration), `tvservice -c "x y"` enables composite with specified mode, `tvservice -h` gives a decent help.  [Brief Help for tvservice](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Which_values_are_valid_for_my_monitor.3F)

Answer (score 2):

`/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o` will Power off the display

Comment: This answer got flagged as Low Quality. Personally, I think it's fine, but you might possibly want to include some explanation of the command or at least some links to more explanation, just to clarify.